# Empty OpenLayers canvas after DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, dom, html5-canvas, openlayers

I want a user to be able to quickly switch to a function located in the sidebar. When sHe clicks on the particular div in the sidebar, I want that div to move into the main area and the div in the main area to move into the sidebar (swap content). Therefore I implemented a javascript function that swaps css classes and DOM locations of those divs.

```
var node1 = document.querySelector(".one");
var node2 = document.querySelector(".other");
node1.classList.toggle("other");
node1.classList.toggle("one");
node2.classList.toggle("one");
node2.classList.toggle("other");
var clone1 = node1.cloneNode(true);
var clone2 = node2.cloneNode(true);
node2.parentNode.replaceChild(clone1, node2);
node1.parentNode.replaceChild(clone2, node1);
```

Works fine, for example with pictures in the divs. If I put a simple OpenLayers map into one of those divs, it shows as it should, until I click and swap the map (either into the main area or into the sidebar). On an empty canvas, I get the control and attribution buttons (of which at least the latter don't work) only.

```
"use_strict";
var Map = {};
Map.locationLonLat = [0, 51.477222];
Map.zoom = 15;

Map.initMap = function() {
    var map = new ol.Map({
        target: "map",
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.OSM(),
                alpha: true,
                isBaseLayer: true,
            }),
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
            center: new ol.proj.fromLonLat(Map.locationLonLat),
            zoom: Map.zoom,
        }),
    });
}
```

While all I probably need is a map refresh (and I tried some of the methods offered on Stackoverflow, like refresh, redraw, render, updateSize etc.), I also tried to initialize the map again (as I originally did) - to no avail.

```
<div class="sidebar" onclick="Util.swapNodes(event); Map.initMap();">
```

Any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, got it fixed. The point was to do two things:

First, I had to clear the DOM from the the OperLayers-generated div which holds the map and its buttons (and probably a reference to the "old" map at a different DOM location); its class is `ol-viewport`.

Second, after swapping the nodes (as shown in the code above) I also had to change the ID of the map node; at least I did not find a way to directly "refresh" the old ID.

So, what I did was this:

```
var mapNode = document.querySelector(".map"); // finds the class
if (mapNode.parentNode.classList.contains("one")) {
    mapNode.id = "mapone"; // change the id
    document.querySelector(".ol-viewport").remove(); // remove old div
    map.setTarget("mapone"); // re-set target to new id
} else if (mapNode.parentNode.classList.contains("other")) {
    mapNode.id = ("mapother"); // change the id
    document.querySelector(".ol-viewport").remove(); // remove old div
    map.setTarget("mapother");  // re-set target to new id
}
```